# How to open files in different ChangeList(s) into default change list?

Tags: perforce

Let's say I have few files under CL: 123 and few files under CL:456 . How do I open all the files together in one changelist or into a default changelist so that I can submit them together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the P4 client:

```
p4 reopen -c <changelist#> //path/to/file
```

...will put it in your default changelist

In P4V, select all of the files you want to move to another changelist. You can either drag-n-drop them to the preferred changelist, or right-click and choose *Move to Another Changelist...*